# VSCode: Open workspace file in split editor

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In the VS Code, we have a split editor. I can split vertically, but every new file I open gets opened on the right side.

Now, I have two folders in the workspace. I want files from one folder to be opened on the right side and the second folder to be opened on the left side.
For example:

> ->Workspace
> ->Folder 1 (Should open in right split)
> ->Folder 2 (Should open in left split)

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omVhU.png)

Comment: I'm not sure it is even possible.